# Impossible to select items DragonBar of Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

When I open Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11, I can't select the items in the DragonBar. For example I click on Tools and the items like Transcribe Recording do not work. Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your status message says that the profile is not ready for dictation. This means that the profile is opened but you have not performed an Audio Setup yet for the microphone that is attached to your computer. You have to do that before you can start dictating.

Comment: Hi @user99572isfine, I know that Dragon is able to transcibe audio file (e.g. mp3) in which the voice is not mine. How does Dragon work if the voice of the speaker in the audio file is unknow for Dragon? To create my profile should be usuless (maybe).

Comment: @Gennaro, You have to use a trained profile for Premium. There is no way around that as far as I know. It takes 20 minutes or so, just do it.